# Multisite Issue on Subdomain's article pages

Tags: posts, multisite, subdomains, 500-internal-error

I created an article under the subdomain that is in my multisite.
Let's call the subdomain  ztak.mydomain.com
When I go to the main page of ztak.mydomain.com, the page shows appropriately.
When I click any of the article that is in my home page, I get redirected to a blank white page (500 Error).

I checked to make sure my virtual host is setup correctly
.htaccess is setup correctly
database is setup correctly

Not exactly sure what's causing this. My dev works just fine. I copied the cod e and are exact. My only guess is that something else is in the server, where ztak.domain.com lives, that's causing 500 Error, but haven't been able to narrow it down yet.

Anyone encountered this? If yes, how did you resolved the issue?

Comment: This would be a white screen of death with a http 500 error code. This is your Apache servers way of saying "I asked PHP to do stuff, but something went wrong, I don't know what it is though, ask PHP, here's the standard 500 error code". You need to look up your PHP error logs to find out what the actual error message is

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

As Tom mentions in his comment, a 500 error is just a generic error code for a php error. In most server environments, you can go to your `wp-config.php` file and make sure `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` is set. This will try to print the actual PHP error to the screen.

After that, fix the PHP error(s) you see and you should be golden!

If all your code is the same, and it is working on your dev environment but not your production server, I'd suggest checking PHP versions. PHP 5.x and PHP 7.x have a lot of differences. Many things that were warnings in the older version are now fatal errors in the newer version, and some features changed which could cause functions and variables to no longer work and throw fatal errors.

If you have trouble fixing your PHP error after you get a print-out of it, just make a question about it and we'll help you out with that too.